# Visualising the absolute value homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the Artin's "Algebra" book the fibres of the absolute value homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{C}^\times \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\times$ defined as $\phi(a) = \lvert a \rvert$ are visualised by concentric circles around $0$.

[image]

I have difficulties interpreting it. Is there any coordinate system implied? From the text, it seems to me that the radius of the circles corresponds to $\text{im}\;\phi$, but how do we arrive at the circle shape?

Sorry if it's too elementary and thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each radius is exactly the norm.

Think about each $z=x+iy$ in polar coordinates, so $z=re^{i\theta}$.  Each circle will be of radius $r$.  The fibers of this homomorphism will be all $z$ that have the same absolute value, so all $z=re^{i\theta}$ that have the same radius $r$.

And the radius of the circle does correspond to $\text{Im }\phi$.  The circle shape denotes all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ that are in the same fiber.  If the inner circle is of radius $r_0$, each point on the circle is in the fiber corresponding to $r_0$.  The same is true for $r_1,r_2$, etc.